# Group By not grouping as expected?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to calculate monthly sum, using this query.

```
SELECT
     fld_year
    , fld_month
    , CONVERT(nvarchar(7), fld_ConsDate, 121) AS fld_ConsDate
    , fld_ConsumptionValue
    , fld_Id
FROM (
    SELECT
         YEAR(DATEADD(MINUTE, fld_TZAM - 6360, fld_ConsDateTime)) AS fld_year
        , MONTH(DATEADD(MINUTE, fld_TZAM- 6360, fld_ConsDateTime)) AS fld_month
        , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, fld_ConsDateTime), 0) AS fld_ConsDate
        , SUM(fld_EnergyTotalIndexValue) AS fld_ConsumptionValue
        , MAX(fld_Id) AS fld_Id
    FROM tbl_EM_DeviceEnergyHourlyConsumption
    WHERE fld_Deleted = 0
        AND fld_Active = 1
        AND fld_CalculationState = 2
        AND fld_DeviceId IN (18)
        AND fld_ConsDateTime >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -1*(fld_TZAM) + 6360, '2017-05-01 00:00:00')
        AND fld_ConsDateTime < DATEADD(MINUTE, -1*(fld_TZAM) + 6360, '2017-08-01 00:00:00')
        AND fld_DeviceOrganizationId IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.fn_OrganizationSubList(2))
    GROUP BY 
        YEAR(DATEADD(MINUTE, fld_TZAM - 6360, fld_ConsDateTime)), 
        MONTH(DATEADD(MINUTE, fld_TZAM - 6360, fld_ConsDateTime)),
        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, fld_ConsDateTime), 0),
)T ORDER BY fld_ConsDate ASC
```

The result I expect is

```
fld_year   fld_month     fld_ConsDate     fld_ConsumptionValue   fld_Id
 2017          5            2017-05              294.1340           
 2017          6            2017-06              222.7527           
 2017          7            2017-07              318.2111
```

But instead I get 2 values from each month

```
fld_year   fld_month     fld_ConsDate     fld_ConsumptionValue   fld_Id
   2017          5            2017-05              260.2158           
   2017          6            2017-06              193.4958           
   2017          5            2017-06              33.9182
   2017          6            2017-07              29.2569           
   2017          7            2017-07              264.8147           
   2017          7            2017-08              53.3964
```

I can't seem to figure it out any tips for me? Anyone can show me where my logic gone wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try add distinct in your query **select distinct fld_year**

Comment: The grouping on `fld_ConstDate` includes day but you are truncating that in the results with the `CONVERT` expression. You could use the the `CONVERT` expression in the `GROUP BY` to group by only year and month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only one row per month, why are you including a third aggregation key?  Something like this would seem to be what you want:

```
   SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(MINUTE, fld_TZAM - 6360, fld_ConsDateTime)) AS fld_year,
          MONTH(DATEADD(MINUTE, fld_TZAM - 6360, fld_ConsDateTime)) AS fld_month,
          DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, MIN(fld_ConsDateTime)), 0) AS fld_ConsDate,
          . . .
    GROUP BY YEAR(DATEADD(MINUTE, fld_TZAM - 6360, fld_ConsDateTime)), 
             MONTH(DATEADD(MINUTE, fld_TZAM - 6360, fld_ConsDateTime))
```